# Cron Task which displays something (task launched but nothing happens)

Tags: linux, bash, cron, xserver

I well used the command "crontab -e" and added this task :

```
* * * * * * bash /home/user1/launcher.sh
```

The content of launcher.sh is :

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/home/user1/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

/usr/bin/gedit
```

Permissions of launcher.sh are 777.

I was expecting to see gedit launched every minute....but nothing happens. Why ?

I think crontab well launch "launcher.sh", as i can see in syslog :

```
Feb  7 22:58:01 librempc CRON[5922]: (user1) CMD (bash /home/user1/launcher.sh)
Feb  7 22:58:01 librempc CRON[5921]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: The `DISPLAY` environment variable isn't set in the `cron` environment, so it doesn't have access to the X server.

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned , you can add "DISPLAY=:0 " to your crontab record  like * * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script  , also try running it as your user not the root as x-server authority may have another opinion

Comment: If you are trying to experiment with cron, then a non-interactive command would be a much better suited target.  For example, `date > /tmp/cron.timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Cron executes tasks with very few environnement variables.

It was well explained there :
[cron & the environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

For the environment variable "PATH", it's possible to define it in the bash script of the task itself :

```
PATH=/home/user1/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

But for the environment variable "DISPLAY" (which is mandatory if the task you launch display something), it must be precised in cron file directly.

```
* * * * * * DISPLAY=:0 bash /home/user1/launcher.sh
```